# How to align the center of imageview to top of viewgroup?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to align the center of imageview to top of viewgroup?
I want to align center of circular image (red circle) to top of the viewgroup (green rectangle)

[image]

Comment: post your layout

Comment: The answer would be different for different parent views. Please provide your code so the answer would be more specific.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<View
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />
```

Comment: Thanks! That works fine!

Comment: this is not good answer: 1. negative margin 2. margin depends on View height

Comment: Depends on image height which is constant, so it works fine

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/some_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#77ff77"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:src="#f00"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/some_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/some_layout" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]